# Javascript API documenting framework with lightweight mark-up

Tags: javascript, markdown, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, jsdoc

I'm seeking a Javascript API documenting framework with features similar to JSDoc, but would use easy-to-type restructured text or markdown in the code comments (not html)

Bonus: would integrate well with Sphinx. However, I don't want to maintain separate documentation, but generate API documentation from comments.

http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/

Comment: Found this nice summary of different tools (other langs included tool): http://blog.pamelafox.org/2011/05/roundup-developer-documentation_06.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found JSDuck the most suitable for the task:

https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck

Comment: Warning: JSDuck is no more maintained! :cry:

Comment: Thank you Josh. This answer was written more than 10 years ago, so it is likely.

Answer (score 3):

[InvisibleJS](http://projects.chrome-life.com/invisible/docs/index.html) supports markdown and a variety of other formats.

Also take a look at [docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/).

Comment: Thanks. These both frameworks where pretty much oriented specific use cases of their authors and could not help me as general API documentation tool.

Comment: docco is fantastic, and has been ported to several different languages, including Python and .NET.

Answer (score 1):

JSDoc 3 now supports markdown by a plugin. You can configure markdown support by adding the line

```
"plugins": [ "plugins/markdown" ],
```

to your configuration JSON file.

Now, starting JSDoc with `-c conf.json` will enable markdown support.

Answer (score 1):

For those who still searching for a markdown plugin for jsdoc-toolkit, please have a look at plug-ins called 'smartdown' in the following links

https://github.com/sproutcore/docs

(More reference on syntax : http://guides.sproutcore.com/documentation_guidelines.html)

I tried it with sphinx through the following templates (jsdoc-toolkit-rst-template, jsdoc-for-sphinx), and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

For very light-weight markup, check out [yamdog](https://github.com/axelpale/yamdog). It parses comment blocks for Markdown and [YAML](https://yaml.org/). Unlike javadoc-based alternatives like [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/) and [Dox](https://github.com/tj/dox), yamdog does not have any magic keywords for you to memorize. Therefore, it prevents the comments beginning to look like another kind of code. It might not be as feature-rich and well-integrated as JSDoc but still it does the job and keeps things simple. Sphinx integration is not on the roadmap for now, unfortunately. Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.

Here is an example of a yamdog comment block from [tapspace](https://github.com/taataa/tapspace) lib:

```
// tapspace.Point:polarOffset(distance, angle)
//
// Get the point at the given *distance* at the *angle*.
//
// Parameters:
//   distance
//     a number on the basis or a Distance.
//   angle
//     a number in radians on the basis or a Direction.
//
// Return
//   a Point
//
```

Only thing yamdog needs is the comment block to start with a certain string, like "tapspace" in this case. Rest is up to you as long as it is valid YAML/Markdown. Typing Markdown can be tedious too, so see [yamdog decorators](https://axelpale.github.io/yamdog/api#yamdogdecorators) for easy ways to include tables of contents, automatic links, and more.